# Running task :api:endpointsDiscoveryDocs on gradle results in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -h

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine, gradle

Using Android Studio 3.0, I tried to run an appengine module:

```
./gradlew :api:endpointsDiscoveryDocs
```

but an error is returned:

```
Execution failed for task ':api:endpointsDiscoveryDocs'.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -h

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -h 
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenApiConfigAction.loadClasses(GenApiConfigAction.java:109) 
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenApiConfigAction.genApiConfig(GenApiConfigAction.java:90) 
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetDiscoveryDocAction.getDiscoveryDoc(GetDiscoveryDocAction.java:78) 
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetDiscoveryDocAction.execute(GetDiscoveryDocAction.java:59) 
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:69) 
at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.server.task.GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.generateDiscoveryDocs(GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.java:137)
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? (What is class -h?!)
Is this a configuration issue? I tried searching for a "-h" in the project, but found nothing out of the ordinary. Does anyone have an idea why this issue occurred?

The Top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

File api/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'

        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

//apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.0'

    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

    compile('com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.9')

    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.12'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    compile group: 'org.tuckey', name: 'urlrewritefilter', version: '4.0.4'

    compile group: 'com.google.appengine.tools', name: 'appengine-gcs-client', version: '0.8'

    compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-oauth2', version: 'v2-rev129-1.22.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
appengine {
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")
        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            //promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }
    //downloadSdk = true
    //appcfg {
    //    oauth2 = true
    //}
    //endpoints {
    //    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    //    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    //}
}
endpointsServer {
    hostname = "sample.project.hostname"
}
group = "com.test.api.projectname"
version = 1
```

I had to ask this here, googling did not result in anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

This api build.gradle file seems to resolve the issue:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'

        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

//apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.0'

    implementation 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

    implementation('com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.9')

    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.12'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation group: 'org.tuckey', name: 'urlrewritefilter', version: '4.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}

appengine {

    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")

        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            //promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }

    //downloadSdk = true
    //appcfg {
    //    oauth2 = true
    //}
    //endpoints {
    //    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    //    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    //}
}

endpointsServer {
    hostname = "path.to.project.hostname"
}

group = "project.package.name"
version = 1
```

This dependency has been commented out:

```
//classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
```